# How to import json file to mongo through mac terminal?

Tags: json, mongodb

I'm using this command

```
mongoimport --db test --collection bankdata --drop --file bank_data.json --port 27017 --host 127.0.0.1
```

to import a json file, but when I do it I get this message

> Failed: error unmarshaling bytes on document #0: JSON decoder out of sync - data changing underfoot?
>   2016-05-24T08:00:31.552-0600    imported 0 documents

Comment: You could use [`--jsonArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--jsonArray) option

Comment: @blackbishop how could i write it? I'm new to mongo, I just started yesterday!

Comment: @blackbishop it worked! thank you

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to import json array ,so you need to add --jsonArray option according to documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/

> mongoimport --jsonArray --db test --collection bankdata --drop --file
>   bank_data.json